# Выборка нужного поля

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Как сделать выборку из нужной мне строки с другого сайта?

Comment: Берёте другой сайт, находите нужную строку и выбираете :) Сформулируйте вопрос точнее: что, где, как, чем вы хотите выбирать.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего использовать регулярки в сервер-сайд скрипте, а не из явы-скрипт.

На пхп:

```
$val=file_get_contents(url);
preg_match(re,$val,$matches);
```

Если же всё-таки надо мучить сторону клиента подобными выкрутасами, то используйте AJAX - получите ответ в html-виде, а там уже распарсите регуляркой как нужно!

Только не забудьте "dot matches new line". ))

Ну и гугол тебе в помощь! :)